# Label of Input Form rounding at weird place

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap for styling and created this input using the input form classes of Bootstrap

But for some reason some weird rounding between the label and the input space happens when loading the page.

[image]

It might have something todo with me using astro and made a component of this input but still no idea.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Zeitpunkt des Aufhörens</span>
    </div>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please post all RELEVANT HTML, CSS and frameworks in the correct versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input-group-prepend` class is a Bootstrap 4 class. Remove the `<div class="input-group-prepend">` element and the problem will be gone.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Zeitpunkt des Aufhörens</div>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you can use multiple elements with `input-group-text` in the same input group and they will be styled accordingly. You don't need any additional CSS or classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Zeitpunkt des Aufhörens</div>
    <div class="input-group-text">Second text</div>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    <div class="input-group-text">Third text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The [migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms) has a note about that change.

> Dropped `.input-group-append` and `.input-group-prepend`. You can now just add buttons and `.input-group-text` as direct children of the input groups.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

Actually input-group-text class contain border-radius css in it by default so if you want to remove it just add one more class which is rounded-0. Please check below updated code :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Input Group Example</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-group my-3 mx-auto px-4">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 rounded-start-2" id="basic-addon1">{label}</span>
    </div>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Ty, it works for me now! I thought this should be the default case for the input-group thingy but seems like it isn't.

Comment: Wait acutally this isnt quite how I wanted it, now it stopped doing the weird rounding but  also on the left side of the label. I tried using the class `rounded-left` but then I get the exact same result as in the beginning.

Comment: @Luke, Now fixed. You can check again

Comment: 1) OP is using 5.0.2 and not 5.3.0 and 2) There is no need for additional classes (even in 5.0.2) as everything works if you follow the documentation and use the appropriate elements.